# Nullpointer Exception when passing JButton actionListener to another Java Class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jpanel, cardlayout

I have two classes (`Main_Menu` and `CancelListener`). When i called an instance of my `CancelListener` to use the proper `actionPerformed` method, i get a `NullPointerException`.

In my MainMenu.java class, i declare the button like this:

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(new CancelListener());
```

Here is my CancelListener() class.

```
class CancelListener implements ActionListener {

    private Main_Menu menu;
    public JPanel mpan;

    public CancelListener() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {


        System.out.println("worked");
        try {

            CardLayout c1 = (CardLayout) (menu.MainPanel.getLayout());
            c1.show(menu.MainPanel, "AppPanel");
        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Exception here " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Further Information: `MainPanel` is a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout` structure. On the Cancel Button, i want to show a particular Panel. I wanted to separate my button view class from the button logic? it works when i dont use a separate class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `menu` variable to be set:

In CancelListener class:

```
private Main_Menu menu;

public CancelListener(Main_Menu menu) {
    this.menu = menu;
}
```

Then, when constructing:

```
button.addActionListener(new CancelListener(this));
```

Comment: @Warz: Yup that's it (1+). Whenever you get a NullPointerException (NPE), always check the reference variables used on the line that causes the exception and find out which is null. Then it's often easy to check back in the code to see why it is null (here you never initialize the menu variable before using it).

Comment: Genius. Thanks alot for this. I will choose this answer when SO lets me in 4 minutes. Thanks again

Comment: any idea how you would do this in nested classes?